# How do I prevent UITabBarItem's title from being overwritten by the controller title?

Tags: ios, swift

If I set the tab bar item title in the storyboard or from code (see below), it is changed to that tab's view controller title when I tap the tab and the controller loads. I don't want this.

I want the tab bar item title that I set in the storyboard or from code to remain, without being changed. How do I achieve that?

I still want to set the controller title for the UINavigationController to show on back buttons etc.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tabBarItem.title = "Keep me"

    // But this overrides it, which I don't want.
    title = "Don't let me change the tab bar title"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change uiviewcontroller title independent of tabbar item title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615637/how-to-change-uiviewcontroller-title-independent-of-tabbar-item-title)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can change

```
title = "Don't let me change the tab bar title"
```

to

```
navigationItem.title = "Don't let me change the tab bar title"
```

edit:

```
override var title: String? {
    didSet{
        tabBarItem.title = "you want"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a simplified example – in real life, the view controller under that tab uses [Turbolinks](github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios) which sets the title. But I guess that we could then tweak Turbolinks and make sure it sets only the navigationItem title.

Comment: @HenrikN well, you may override the `title` property of the view controller and set `tabBarItem.title` to what you want in `didSet`.

Comment: We ended up overriding Turbolinks to assign `navigationItem`, based on this answer. Thank you! https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios/issues/101#issuecomment-335411356